# jQuery in rails: replace input field with another input type

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Within my `js.erb` file, I successfully grab the input element I want to replace.  As a test: I can easily replace that input element with a `<p>` element:

```
$(‘.selector_for_input_element’).replaceWith("<p>hello world</p>");
```

I can even successfully do the same thing with `content_tag`:

```
$('.selector_for_input_element').replaceWith("<%= content_tag(:p, "hello world") %>");
```

However: when I attempt to replace the `input` element (which happens to be a select box) with a text field: nothing happens:

```
$('.selector_for_input_element').replaceWith("<%= text_field_tag("name") %>");
```

With the rails form helpers: how can I successfully swap out the selected input element, and replace it with a text field?

Comment: any errors in your JS console or `rails server` output?

Comment: no, no errors in either.

Comment: Could it be because you're not escaping the quotes? ie. `$('.selector_for_input_element').replaceWith("<%= text_field_tag('name') %>");` may work

Comment: Interesting: that didn't work, but when I took your suggestion and switched the quote types around it did work.  I'm not quite sure why this works: `$('.selector_for_input_element').replaceWith('<%= text_field_tag("name") %>');`

Comment: not quite sure either, likely something with html safe. Glad I could help though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving the comments to an answer.
For anyone else looking, the issue is related to string safety in `.js.erb`.

Flipping quotes to `''` on the outside and `""` on the inside of the JS statement worked.